# Reuse React.useCallback() function across multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, usecallback

I have a few components that all call the same function on an `onPress` handler, let's say it looks like the following:

```
function MyComponent () {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const updateThing = React.useCallback((thingId: string) => {
    dispatch(someActionCreator(thingId))
    someGlobalFunction(thingId)
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <View>
      <NestedComponent onUpdate={updateThing} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

I want to move this function outside of the component so I can re-use it, thinking it would look something like this:

```
const updateThing = React.useCallback(myFunction)
```

However, it has a dependency of `dispatch` that I need to pass in and add to the dependency array.

How can I break this function out for reuse while also getting the performance gain from `useCallback`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can write a custom hook like

```
export const useUpdateThinkg = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const updateThing = React.useCallback((thingId: string) => {
    dispatch(someActionCreator(thingId))
    someGlobalFunction(thingId)
  }, [dispatch])
  return { updateThing };
}
```

---

And then use it like

```
import { useUpdateThing } from 'path/to/updateThing'
function MyComponent () {
  const { updateThing} = useUpdateThing();

  return (
    <View>
      <NestedComponent onUpdate={updateThing} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer - thank you. It's taking a while to get used to thinking in Hooks but what an elegant solution. Will accept answer when SO lets me in a few minutes.

Comment: Glad to have helped Alex :-) and yeah hooks are a bit of a learning curve